# changing light switches

Tags: electrical

I am changing my light switches I have it hooked up the way the directions say. When I turn the breaker on it cuts the light on, but when I turn the switch off it kicks the breaker. And with the switch in the off position the breaker will not cut on.

Comment: Could use a new answer pretty soon my wife is wanting to take a shower

Comment: If you need an answer immediately, I would suggest calling an electrician to come fix it.

Comment: "hooked it up the way the directions say" requires that you know which wires are which (hot vs neutral vs switched hot). Put the old switch for the shower back in the way it was so you're wife can shower while you research about residential electrical circuits and procure a tester.

Comment: HOW DO I TELL WHICH IS WHICH

Comment: @charlesbalser, please don't YELL. What you say doesn't make a ton of sense. A switch in the off position makes no connection between it's terminals, so why would turning it off create the situation. Is this a 3-way switch; does it have 3 terminals (2 gold, 1 black)?

Comment: Got it fixed all 3 sets

Comment: You SHOULD NOT be messing with such things if you do not own a tester/meter and do not know how to use it. This is a key rule.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a multi-meter or AC tester at the hardware store and read the directions and practice with it on another switched circuit that works correctly. Get a book at the library about residential wiring theory and practice, for your country.

Keep in mind the following:

- The nature of residential wiring makes wire color an unreliable indicator of wire function.
- Never assume any wire is not energized, always confirm with a tester.
- Utilize proper lock-out/tag-out procedures to prevent someone from energizing equipment whilst you are working on it.
- A simple switch "makes" or "breaks" a hot conductor on it's way to the load. No neutral conductors attach to them except for some specialty type switches (timers, lighted switches, programmable switches).
- If you do not know what you are doing and you do not want to spend the time and energy to learn... hire it done. It will save you $$ in the end.